# classify data into categories using python

Tags: python

im a beginner in python and i have this project where i have to classify my data into different categories, i want to access to my categorie list, i tried the following as you can see  here but i keep receiving the same error

i would appreciate any help or solution to my problem

```
 insport = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[3] )
         if insport:
            data["cat"]='sport'
            nsport=nsport+1
         else :
            insante = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[1] )
            if insante :
                data["cat"]='sante'
                nsante=nsante+1
            else :
                inpolitique = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[2])
                if  inpolitique:
                    data["cat"]='politique'
                    npoli=npoli+1
                else:
                    incalture = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[6] )
                    if incalture:
                        data["cat"]='culture'
                        ncalt=ncalt+1
                    else:
                        inreligion = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[4])
                        if inreligion:
                            data["cat"]='religion'
                            nrelig=nrelig+1
                        else:
                            ineducation = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[5] )
                            if ineducation:
                                data["cat"]='social'
                                neduc=neduc+1
                            else:
                                    print(" the tweet---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                                    print(text)
```

this the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NIHAD\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\classification.py", line 52, in <module>
    ifin = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[0] )
  File "C:\Users\NIHAD\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\classification.py", line 52, in <genexpr>
    ifin = any(ele in text for ele in categorie[0] )
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

and this is my categorie list:

[[(1, 'education'), (2, 'sante'), (3, 'politique'), (4, 'sport'), (5, 'religion'), (6, 'social'), (7, 'culture')]]

Comment: Please consider to use `elif` instead of these amount of nested `if`/`else`.

Comment: And please provide the correct `categorie` data. Your list of a list of tuples would throw a `IndexError: list index out of range` already  in the first line.

Comment: They should all be `ele[1] in text...` - if you want to match the word in the tuple with the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a different, simpler approach. I use `texts` with texts containing category names only as an example.
When the name of the category contained in one of the texts is identified you are ready to save the text with the category found in your database. However, this assigns only one category for each text.

```
texts=[
 "bla bla bla santebla bla bla ",
 "bla bla bla sport bla bla bla ",
 "bla bla bla education bla bla bla ",
 "bla bla bla social  bla bla bla ",
 "bla bla bla religion bla bla bla ",
 "bla bla bla politique bla bla bla ",
 "bla bla bla culture  bla bla bla "
]

counts={
 "sante":0,
 "sport":0,
 "education":0,
 "social":0,
 "religion":0,
 "politique":0,
 "culture":0
}

categorie= [[(1, 'education'), (2, 'sante'), (3, 'politique'), (4, 'sport'), (5, 'religion'), (6, 'social'), (7, 'culture')]]

for i,t in enumerate(texts):
    for c in categorie[0]:
        catid=c[0]
        catname=c[1]
        if catname in t:
            counts[catname]+=1
            print("you can save texts[",i,"] with catname:",catname," or catid:",catid, "in your database")


print("Show categories counts:")
print(counts)
```

output:

```
you can save texts[ 0 ] with catname: sante  or catid: 2 in your database
you can save texts[ 1 ] with catname: sport  or catid: 4 in your database
you can save texts[ 2 ] with catname: education  or catid: 1 in your database
you can save texts[ 3 ] with catname: social  or catid: 6 in your database
you can save texts[ 4 ] with catname: religion  or catid: 5 in your database
you can save texts[ 5 ] with catname: politique  or catid: 3 in your database
you can save texts[ 6 ] with catname: culture  or catid: 7 in your database
Show categories counts:
{'sante': 1, 'sport': 1, 'education': 1, 'social': 1, 'religion': 1, 'politique': 1, 'culture': 1}
```